# Join a table to a table function with table.column as a parameter

Tags: t-sql

Is there a way to have a statement of a kind:

```
SELECT <table>.ID, <table>.Parameter
FROM <table> t
  JOIN <tableValuedFunction> (<table>.Parameter) tt ON t.ID = tt.ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are after is a query that uses `cross apply`.

```
SELECT <table>.ID, <table>.Parameter
FROM <table> t
CROSS APPLY <tableValuedFunction> (<table>.Parameter)
```

Comment: thanks, that was the answer. I am sorry it took me almost a year to finally mark this appropriately, just noticed that I didn't at the time

Answer (score -1):

In Sql Server, use EXEC with dinamic query:

```
Declare @sSql Varchar(max)
Declare @table VArchar(25) = 'table'
declare @colum VArchar(25) = 'column'

SET @sSql = 'SELECT table.ID, table.Parameter
            FROM table t
            JOIN tableValuedFunction ('''+@table+'.'+@colum+''') tt ON t.ID = tt.ID'

EXEC (@sSql)
```

Comment: :) unfortunately.. I don't need to pass the name of the column as a parameter. I need to pass the value of the column. thanks for trying though